# whole activity push up when start typing on EditText

Tags: android

This happens when i use

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`

[image]

And my layout looks like this when i use `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`

[image]

I already have `ScrollView` inside layout but I don't know why it behaves like this:

Comment: what exactly you want?

Comment: explain your question....

Comment: Please click on above link to see screen shots.

Comment: do not set any InputMode and check what happens

Comment: actually i want in my layout that when i start typing on edittext layout should only push up internal content which is in scrollview not Actionbar/Titlebar. but it takes whole activity up.

Comment: It is default behavior of android OS. When you click on edittext whole view scrolls up. There should be some setting i guess. Check android docs.

Comment: still facing same issue after remove inputmode

Comment: i want it to behave like chat screen of whatsapp or any other messaging app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try and add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to the particular activity in android manifest file

Comment: Feedback text is the toolbar right? whats the size of the toolbar?

Comment: i used android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar and its height set to wrap_content.

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

Comment: give the height as android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" its the default toolbar height given by android

Comment: its height goes just half after set it to "?attr/actionBarSize". i don't know it include statusbar or not. but my problem is still be there. :(
how can i share screen shot in comments?

Comment: Your first screenshot looks proper i guess and it works that way according to android OS config. Don't set the height to wrap_content give some hardcoded value to it.

Comment: thanks, layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" works perfect when i set fitsystemwindows to true.

Comment: good to hear that i could be of some help :) if the post helped please vote for the answer

Comment: sorry to say but i cant vote now.
stackoverflow displaying a message that "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score." but Thank you for help.

Comment: Glad that i could help :)